# Find beginning of the asymptotic expansion of the sum

Tags: summation, asymptotics

Find beginning of the asymptotic expansion of the sum:

$$
(n!)^{-1}\sum^{n}_{k=1}k!
$$

against the function $n^{-i}$, for $i\geq0$ to the nearest $\mathcal{O}(n^{-5})$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Multiply $(n!)^{-1}$ into the sum.  Prove that the result is an asymptotic expansion.